# How to implement circle using MongoDB geometry feature

Tags: mongodb, geometry, geospatial

I want to save circle just like we save polygons in mongodb using geospatial and get that circle when my lat, long exists in that circle.

Answer (score 1):

> Below is the format in this way you can save the circle:
>
> ```
> let mongoose = require('mongoose');
> let Schema = mongoose.Schema;
> require('mongoose-double')(mongoose);
> let SchemaTypes = mongoose.Schema.Types;
>
> let deliveryZones= new Schema({
> name:{type:String},//location name
> location: {
>     'type: {type: String,},//if want to save circle coordinates: type-circle
>     coordinates: {type: Array} // centre coordinates of circle
> },
>  radius: {type:SchemaTypes.Double},// radius of circle
> })
> ```